# Can I display html table on html button?

Tags: html, css, button, html-table

I want to display 3 button which contains 5 values side by side. I want to enhance the display of the button.

Example:

```
1    aombhkjsdhffhf   hehehe     4   5
2    khdjhfhf         dhjfhj     6   7
3    hhkjhdjkhdjh     jhkjhjkh   8   9
```

So, each line above needs to be on a button. So I have 3 buttons, but the display on the buttons needs to be as if I am displaying a table.
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You could just make the table cells look like buttons: `td { border: 1px outset #666; bg: .. }`

Comment: Somewhere a UI Developer about to punch a furry bunny....for useability's sake, how about a more sane looking button with a tooltip to present extended data?

Answer (score 3):

You can put a table inside of the `<button>` tag.

```
<button>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>aombhkjsdhffhf</td>
    <td>hehehe</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</button>
<br>
<button>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>khdjhfhff</td>
    <td>dhjfhj</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</button>
<br>
<button>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>hhkjhdjkhdjk</td>
    <td>jhkjhkjh</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</button>
```

and define the css so that the td element has a certain width:

```
td{width:100px;}
```

See sample on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qRj7g/1/).

Comment: Hey thank you so much. This is exactly my requirement. But, I need to get this thing done with submit button, i.e, with the input tag with type="submit". Sorry, that I told it now, but this is my requirement.

Comment: So, now all the 3 buttons are submit buttons, and if I click any one, each redirects to its own page.

Comment: Hey I got the output...<button type="submit"...........
Thanks a lot! It really heleped

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something you could easily handle with css and javascript. In other words, render a normal html table, use CSS to make each row look like a button, and use javascript to tie an event handler to each row's click.

Html

```
<table>
  <tr class="button">
    <td>aombhkjsdhffhf</td>
    <td>hehehe</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="button">
    <td>khdjhfhf</td>
    <td>jhkjhjkh</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>    
  </tr>
  <tr class="button">
    <td>hhkjhdjkhdjh</td>
    <td>dhjfhj</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>    
  </tr>
</table>
```

Css

```
tr.button {
  /* the css to make each row look like a button */
}
```

Javascript

```
// using jQuery
$('tr.button').click(function() {
  // do whatever here.
});
```

Comment: It would take a bit of work to make a table row look like a button, especially if it simulated hovering and pushing.